# Custom Javascript not being called on Search Display Item Template

Tags: search-results, display-template

I cannot determine why javascript function is not being called when paging through search result pages.  On the first page load js executes as expected.  When I do a hard refresh it executes TruncateComments function as expected.  When I page to page 2 only "test" and "undefined" are printed to the console.  How do I set this up, so the TruncateComments gets executed on a hard page refresh and paging ahead?

```
RegisterSod("jquery-3.2.1.min.js", Srch.U.replaceUrlTokens("~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/custom/scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"));
RegisterSod("jquery.truncate.js", Srch.U.replaceUrlTokens("~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/custom/scripts/jquery.truncate.js"));
RegisterSodDep("jquery.truncate.js", "jquery-3.2.1.min.js");

AddPostRenderCallback(ctx, function() {
    console.log("test");
    if(typeof truncate === "undefined") {
        console.log("undefined");
        EnsureScriptFunc("jquery.truncate.js", null, function() {
            console.log("EnsureScriptFunc");
            TruncateComments();
        });
    } else {
        console.log("defined");
        TruncateComments();
    }
});

function TruncateComments() {
    console.log("TruncateComments");
    var comments = $('#LWICommentsValue').html();
    var truncatedComments = jQuery.truncate(comments, {
        length: 10
    });
    $('#LWICommentsValue').replaceWith(truncatedComments);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paging is asynchronous hence the load events will not get fired.

Your best option is to hook an event handler the paging object click and then call `TruncateComments` inside that.

Example

```
$(document).on('click', '#PageLinkNext', function(){alert('test');});
```

You can use Browser Dev Tools to find the exact id of the element

Comment: Thanks.  Can you provide an example?